# ;It shows runtime when i am using an array of pointers to strings,or is it because i cant pass data to a function from array of pointers

Tags: c, pointers, reverse, c-strings, function-definition

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    //reversal function

    void reverseString(char* str)
    {
        int l, i;
        char *begin_ptr, *end_ptr, ch;
        l = strlen(str);
        begin_ptr = str;
        end_ptr = str;

        //move  the ptr  to the final pos
        for (i = 0; i < l - 1; i++)
            end_ptr++;
        //pointer swaping
        for (i = 0; i < l / 2; i++)
        {
            ch = *end_ptr;
            *end_ptr = *begin_ptr;
            *begin_ptr = ch;
            begin_ptr++;
            end_ptr--;
        }
    }

    // Driver code
```

---------------------------------main---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
the function call sends the address of the first string in the  array

```
int main()
{
    char *str[ ] = {"To err is human...","But to really mess things up...","One needs to know C!!"};
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
    reverseString(str[i]);  //funtion call
    printf("Reverse of the string: %s\n", str[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry, why do you write a for loop to get the pointer to the end of the string, and you don't write simply `end_ptr += l;` ???  think that `strlen()` already navigated the whole array to get to the `\0` char.

Comment: Why do you think you can't pass the data of an array of pointers, what error or problem do you observe?  If you don't describe de problem it's difficult to make a diagnostic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not modify a string literal. Any attempt to modify a string literal results in undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

You should declare a to-dimensional array like

```
enum { N = 32 };
char str[][N] = 
{
    "To err is human...",
    "But to really mess things up...",
    "One needs to know C!!"
};
```

Pay attention to that the function revreseString is too complicated. Also it is better when the function returns pointer to the reversed string. The function can be defined the following way using pointers

```
char * reverseString( char *s )
{
    if ( *s )
    {
        for ( char *p = s, *q = s + strlen( s ); p < --q; ++p )
        {
            char c = *p;
            *p = *q;
            *q = c;
        }
    }

    return s;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * reverseString( char *s )
{
    if ( *s )
    {
        for ( char *p = s, *q = s + strlen( s ); p < --q; ++p )
        {
            char c = *p;
            *p = *q;
            *q = c;
        }
    }

    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 32 };
    char s[][N] = 
    {
        "To err is human...",
        "But to really mess things up...",
        "One needs to know C!!"
    };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( s ) / sizeof( *s ); i++ )
    {
        puts( reverseString( s[i] ) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
...namuh si rre oT
...pu sgniht ssem yllaer ot tuB
!!C wonk ot sdeen enO
```

Comment: Ok, But in  C strings are an array of characters.So can we use the address of each character to modify the string. Is there any other way to do the program using array  of sting pointers. If yes  please explain.

Comment: @KaustuvaKumarSahu As I wrote you may not modify a string literal. If you want to have an array of pointers then you need for each its element dynamically allocate array and copy in each allocated memory a string literal.

Comment: It worked bro thanks.I had to use a temporary character array and variable to do it.

Comment: But during one of the trials i could not used the passed address of the sting to assign  values directly to the charater array, so i had to use another variable.